# Dynamically set self.x from a dictionary key/value pair

Tags: python

I have a slice of code where I want to transform thirty or forty ever-changing key/value pairs into variables under a class. So for instance:

```
for i in dict:
    self.i = dict[i]
```

But of course that would just reset self.i each time. I've tried eval, but you cannot set variables with it, as it reports 'x=1' as invalid syntax. I've tried searching, but I'm not even quite sure what to search...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To update a class instance, you could just use

```
vars(self).update(my_dict)
```

I doubt though this is the best solution for your problem.  Could you provide more details why you think you need this?

Comment: quite, what i was thinking but mine was phrased: `self.__dict__.update(my_dict)`

Comment: Another +1 for the working answer accompanied by advice to search for a better solution to the underlying problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way. [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8281845/577088) is right though -- you should say more about why you want to do this.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, d):
...         for k in d:
...             setattr(self, k, d[k])
... 
>>> f = Foo({'a':'b', 'c':'d'})
>>> f.a
'b'
>>> f.c
'd'
```

Comment: +1 for the working answer accompanied by advice to think through the real design requirements :-)

Answer (score 1):

Python classes have a built-in property called [__dict__](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__).

You can use it like this:

```
>>> class Blah(object):
...    pass
>>> x = Blah()
>>> x.__dict__['what'] = 40
>>> x.what
```

In your case, something like this should work:

```
self.__dict__.update(dict)
```

Comment: I did read somewhere (late last night, I think) a reason why `setattr` is preferable to directly setting `__dict__`'s values. Of course, I can't remember the reasoning now.

Comment: Agreed, setattr is probably better, since \_\_dict__ is more of an implementation detail.